# Does Mule have the ability to simply move/rename a file?

Tags: mule

Is there a way to simply "move/rename" a file in Mule as opposed to a copy?  The flow below performs a copy, but what I really want is to simply rename the file.  The file can be quite large.

```
<file:connector name="Global-StageToInput" fileAge="10000" autoDelete="true" pollingFrequency="30000"/>
<file:connector name="Global-FileInput" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]" />

<flow name="Global-MoveInputFiles">
    <file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Global-StageToInput" path="${stage}"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="Global-FileInput" path="${input}"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to move a file from one directory to another the file aparently vanishes from the directory you are moving .

Back up of this file can be taken using the moveToDirectory in Inbound endpoint

In order to rename the backup file you can use moveToPattern in Inbound endpoint

In order to rename in the destination you can use  outputPattern in Outbound endpoint
You can use the following links to have more ideas

```
<file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="input" path="/tmp/input" moveToDirectory="/tmp/backup" moveToPattern="#[header:originalFilename].backup"/>
<file:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="output" path="/tmp/output" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp]-#[header:originalFilename]"/>
```

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/File+Transport+Reference

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/File+Transport+Reference

http://www.mulesoft.org/connectors/file-connector

If you need only to move  a file from a  folder  to another where you need to rename the file name.

Then use the following code

```
<file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="input" path="/tmp/input"/>
<file:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="output" path="/tmp/output" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp]-#[header:originalFilename]"/>
```

Just only the pattern in the outbound endpoint.

Only the path in the input and output is required .Rest all is not necessary and with mix and match of the option that is there links can be used.  Even the connector-ref is not required for a basic requirement

Comment: I can not find a way to just do a simple old move/rename.  In the snippet Naveen provided, both a "move" of the input file is performed, which is what I want, but also a new "copy" of the file is produced in the outbound endpoint.

Comment: I think what the snippet above does is a copy of the original file to the outbound path, followed by a delete of the file in the inbound.  This is different than a "move".  If I test this with a large file, I can see the files in both the inbound and outbound directories until the flow completes and the file in the inbound is deleted.

Comment: Can you give me more idea on what you want . I hope you needed a move of the file and the snippet is there which is doing it. Do you need to read a file from folder A and move it  to folder B or just to rename a file in the folder A ? There are two things you can do . One is while moving a file from folder A to B you can change its name and then move it , here you can opt to either delete or retain the file in Folder A. If you need to delete the file in folder A then you can optionally Add another folder C where you can take a backup of the file you transfered with a new name(renaming).

Comment: We have our mule flow that deposits a potentially very large file someplace.  We have a separate process not controlled by mule which is looking for the file and is on a cron timer.  We want to avoid the second process from beginning to read a file which mule may be writing.  We originally wanted to have mule write to a temporary directory and then "move" the file to the final location.  A move is pretty much an instantaneous operation in the O.S.  Mule seems to only be able to do a copy->delete which is different than a move.